# MS Access database issue, multiple clients

Tags: .net, ms-access, ms-access-2003

Good morning,
I have a simple WPF app, that reads one table from a access 2003 database that is on my server. I have 2 client pc's that read that table and populate the categories to a listbox on my main app. When i open the application on the server it works fine, but when i run the app from a client i don't get any rows from the database. The folder is shared and can be viewed from network. Is there a problem with MS access and network related issues? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I think some code, how you access the database would be helpful. - And as tip for the future. Just because you're developing a WPF application your problem is not implictely related to it. So if you choose the tags according to your problem, you might get better help. ;o)

Comment: this is my connection string <add name="BlackSheepConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\192.168.2.102\BlackSheepSrv\Data\BlackSheep.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>

Comment: the data access code is correct, because it already works on the pc with the msaccess database on.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should check is that you have access to the shared folder and to the database from the client PC, with the user logged in (try to open the database from the folder explorer).

If this works, make sure that the connection string its ok by using it from the server (this I think you have already done).

Finally, see that you have the provider installed in the client. You can install the last Jet service pack.